# Convert non-pixel css value to px

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As some measurement parameters in `css` are not always in `px` values, how can be such non-pixel value converted to `px`?

Let's have

```
var x = $('#element').css('parameter');
```

and let's say that the value of such `x` variable is `1.2em` or some other string that contains not just number, but also measurement type information (`px`, `em`, `pt`, `cm`, `in`, ...).

What is all-browser solution to convert such `string` into `integer`, having results in `px`?

Comment: jQuery already does this: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2WQqF/

Comment: ^^ Didn't know that. Post as an answer? And do you know how jQuery does it (I'm thinking if I wanted to do the same thing without jQuery)?

Comment: I didn't know jQuery did this, this is great to know! I have been wanting to convert to ems over pixels.

Comment: @j08691 - For any parameters jquery get `px` value? Really? But what if I have such value in string, then what/how..?

Comment: What do you mean by having a value in `string`?

Comment: @Vega - Simple: `var x = '2.4em';`

Comment: @Archer - Read last line in my question. I am not changing anything...

Comment: @Ωmega You could use some conversion, but it is easier to set it to a temp div and get its parameter and remove the div.

Comment: Okay - my bad.  I apologise.  An unfortunate number of people on this site do increase my cynicism.  And ^^ what Vega said.  Was about to say the same myself :)

Comment: @dandavis - `parseInt("2.3em")` will not get result in `px`

Comment: I believe the value is calculated using the [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle) method. It's an unwieldy interface to use, but is well-supported cross-browser.

Comment: i though we got past the ems and needed to numberAtize the "npx" result. use appliedStyle/getComputed style to turn ems into px.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the built-in method `getComputedStyle` which will interpolate any non-`px` value into pixels. For example:

```
var el = document.getElementById('foo'); // has a relative font size

console.log(el.style.fontSize); // "5em"
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(el).fontSize); // "80px"
```

From there you can convert into an integer.

**[Example JsBin](http://jsbin.com/OcEGIRe/1/edit)** and [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle).

Comment: Just for IE9+ (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: Yes, you can fall back to IE's nonstandard [`currentStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535231\(v=vs.85\).aspx) property if you need to support IE8 or before.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#element").css("padding","2em")
var value = parseInt($("#element").css("font-size"));
var padding = 2*value ;
console.log(padding);
```

Comment: You set padding but read font size?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 